# Cannot delete a file from s3 with boto3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to permanently delete a file from S3, using boto3. My buckets are not using versioning.

I have tried two ways:

```python
def remove_aws_object(bucket_name, item_key):
    ''' Provide bucket name and item key, remove from S3
    '''
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                             aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
    delete = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=item_key)
    print(delete)
{'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '61F3C195D373B0C5', 'HostId': 'pigcx1wtIN+Y8RU3zJKliWXcXrHXHzpdAOuGBL64x3V9YefQbWXPZi9B/9F', 'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'pigcx1wtIN+Y8RU3zJKliWXcXrHXHzpdAOuGBL64x3V9YefQbWXPZi9B/9FLazUSsCds8f4=', 'x-amz-request-id': '61F3C195D373B0C5', 'date': 'Thu, 13 Feb 2020 09:07:50 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

As well as via the Object:

```python
def remove_aws_object(bucket_name, item_key):
    ''' Provide bucket name and item key, remove from S3
    '''
    s3_client = boto3.resource('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                             aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)

    my_object = s3_client.Object(bucket_name, item_key)
    a = my_object.delete()
    print(a)
    {'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '6074B9CA870773CE', 'HostId': 'rQoK+x+xcjAw2T3DpTHMWQb4Gq6DzPJy2qFoFHQCYoGwb8/p7700+Nk+6gBIERN', 'HTTPStatusCode': 204, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amz-id-2': 'rQoK+x+xcjAw2TKK833DpTHMWQb4Gq6DzPJy2qFoFHQCYoGwb8/p7700+Nk+6gBIE', 'x-amz-request-id': '6074B9CA870773CE', 'date': 'Thu, 13 Feb 2020 12:02:36 GMT', 'x-amz-version-id': 'null', 'x-amz-delete-marker': 'true', 'server': 'AmazonS3'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}, 'DeleteMarker': True, 'VersionId': 'null'}
```

Both methods work without error, but do not remove the file, I can still see it in the S3 console and I then have to manually delete it. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this only for one particular file, or is it for any file you try? Did the bucket previously have Versioning activated? (The appearance of `DeleteMarker` in the response makes me consider this.) Have you tried this code on a different bucket to see whether it works? (Preferably a new bucket.)

Comment: Tried with a brand new bucket, same results. Even after 14-16 hours my deleted objects are still showing in my bucket.

Comment: The only possibly I can think of is that the credentials used by your app do not have permissions to delete the object. Try using those same credentials with the AWS CLI to delete the object and see whether it provides a more descriptive error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a fairly simple solution, my items are stored within a folder structure, and I needed to pass the folder location, along with the item key.

```py
def remove_aws_object(bucket_name, item_key):
    ''' Provide bucket name and item key, remove from S3
    '''
    folder = "foo/bar/"
    delete_key = folder + item_key
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                             aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
                             aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET)
    delete = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=delete_key)
```

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Created a new bucket in the Amazon S3 management console
- Uploaded a file to the bucket via the management console
- Used your code (first example) to delete the object

The object was successfully deleted.

So, the code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file in question exists? By your response, you get `HttpStatusCode: 204` which means that there is [no content available](https://httpstatuses.com/204) with the parameters you've sent. Can you show an example of your Bucket/key values? I.e. show the exact structure of the string you are passing to those variables?

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding in this answer: 204 does not mean that there is a problem with the request; it simply means that there is no data needed in the response. As per the link in the answer, 204 means "The server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body."

Answer (score 0):

```
delete = s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=item_key.strip())
```

Adding the strip() has helped in my case